# call custom Activity as startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting an Activity for result as

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityA.class),REQUEST_CODE)
```

ActivityA is started. There is a gridview on ActivityA, I want to get the position of selected image in method  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) of caller Activity but I am not getting the way to do that

Comment: `call custom Activity means ?`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Activity A,

`onItemClick()` of `GridView`

```
//create a new intent...
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putInt("position",position);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
//close this Activity...
finish();
```

in Caller Activity,

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        int position = extras.getInt("position");
    }
```

Comment: I did this but caller Activity's onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method not called

Comment: Hey, if my arraylist is just a String, how to get the extras?

Answer (score 0):

To uniquely identify your startActivityForResult() callback , check for similarity and success of Activity A . Follow this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE)
      {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
          {
              Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
              if(extras != null)
              int position = extras.getInt("position");
          }
       }
}
```