# Getting the values when an activity is resumed (put extras and get Extras)

Tags: android

1. I'm creating an music player App where in I have a layout(Main_Activity) which contains 4 buttons namely Play_List_A , Play_List_B , Play and Stop. here if i click on Play_List_A it redirects to a new Activity named songList where list of mp3 files are loaded into a listView, so if I click on the list item it has to redirect me again to the Main_Activity with the song position(Index) and name. I used putExtras() to do this.
2. If I click on Play_List_B its has to start  the same songList Activity and if i click on the list item it has to redirect me to the same Main_Activity with the song Position(Index) and name. I used putExtras() method to do this

How will make both the songs to play one after the other when Play button is clicked

Comment: Please refer to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you need to use startActivityForResult
and check this so question and first answer:
[call custom Activity as startActivityForResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628433/call-custom-activity-as-startactivityforresult)